# SQL Query error (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Having some issues with this search engine I am trying to put together. I'll provide everything to make things easier. I'm a Web Designer and don't usually play around with MySQL so I'm quite sure I am missing something obvious here. I get this error whenever I try to search:

> Error performing query SELECT firstname, lastname, comments FROM test
>   WHERE MATCH (firstname, lastname, comments) AGAINST ('ash')

Thanks

**PHP file (mysql.php)**

```
<?php

// define 'MySQL' class

class MySQL{

private $conId;

private $host;

private $user;

private $password;

private $database;

private $result;

const OPTIONS=4;

public function __construct($options=array()){

if(count($options)!=self::OPTIONS){

throw new Exception('Invalid number of connection parameters');

}

foreach($options as $parameter=>$value){

if(!$value){

throw new Exception('Invalid parameter '.$parameter);

}

$this->{$parameter}=$value;

}

$this->connectDB();

}

// connect to MySQL

private function connectDB(){

if(!$this->conId=mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password)){


throw new Exception('Error connecting to the server');

}

if(!mysql_select_db($this->database,$this->conId)){

throw new Exception('Error selecting database');

}

}

// run query

public function query($query){

if(!$this->result=mysql_query($query,$this->conId)){

throw new Exception('Error performing query '.$query);

}

return new Result($this,$this->result);

}

public function escapeString($value){

return mysql_escape_string($value);

}

}

// define 'Result' class

class Result {

private $mysql;

private $result;

public function __construct(&$mysql,$result){

$this->mysql=&$mysql;

$this->result=$result;

}

// fetch row

public function fetchRow(){

return mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result);

}

// count rows

public function countRows(){

if(!$rows=mysql_num_rows($this->result)){

return false;

}

return $rows;

}

// count affected rows

public function countAffectedRows(){

if(!$rows=mysql_affected_rows($this->mysql->conId)){

throw new Exception('Error counting affected rows');

}

return $rows;

}

// get ID form last-inserted row

public function getInsertID(){

if(!$id=mysql_insert_id($this->mysql->conId)){

throw new Exception('Error getting ID');

}

return $id;

}

// seek row

public function seekRow($row=0){

if(!is_int($row)||$row<0){

throw new Exception('Invalid result set offset');

}

if(!mysql_data_seek($this->result,$row)){

throw new Exception('Error seeking data');

}

}

}

?>
```

**PHP file (processform.php)**

```
<?php

// include MySQL-processing classes

require_once 'mysql.php';

try{

// connect to MySQL

$db=new MySQL(array ('host'=>'localhost','user'=>'xxx','password'=>'xxx','database'=>'xxx'));

$searchterm=$db->escapeString($_GET['searchterm']);

$result=$db->query("SELECT firstname, lastname, comments FROM test WHERE MATCH (firstname, lastname, comments) AGAINST ('$searchterm')");

if(!$result->countRows()){

echo '<div class="maincontainer"><h2>No results were found. Go
back and try a new search.</h2></div>'."n";

}

else{

// display search results

echo '<div class="maincontainer"><h2>Your search criteria
returned '.$result->countRows().' results.</h2>'."n";

while($row=$result->fetchRow()){

echo '<div class="rowcontainer"><p><strong>First Name:
</strong>'.$row['firstname'].'<p><p><strong>Last Name:
</strong>'.$row['lastname'].'</p><p><strong>Comments:
</strong>'.$row['comments'].'</p></div>'."n";

}

}

echo '</div>';

}

catch(Exception $e){

echo $e->getMessage();

exit();

}

?>
```

Comment: can you please changhe this line: 
`throw new Exception('Error performing query '.$query);` to 
`throw new Exception('Error performing query ['.$query.'] Error:['.mysql_error().']');`  and then show us what you get?

Comment: Please remove irrelevant code from your question. For a SQL error the HTML code doesn't matter for example.

Comment: Thanks Nicola, this is what I get: `Error performing query [SELECT firstname, lastname, comments FROM test WHERE MATCH (firstname, lastname, comments) AGAINST ('Enter your search term here')] Error:[Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is obviously no FULLTEXT index on firstname, lastname, comments. You should ask your database administrator to add that index for you.

Comment: I never used fulltext index, but I guess (as with any index) it makes a difference wether you have one combined index covering all the columns or multiple indexes covering one column each (which is the case here). You may want to try ALTER TABLE ... ADD FULLTEXT INDEX( firstname, lastname, comments ).

Be warned though that this might take a while depending on the tables size and should be tried in a testing environment first.